# subfig package displays "figure" below caption

Tags: subfloats

I've included the subfig package in my latex document. The word "figure" is appearing below  the main caption in each figure (even those not using subfloats). Has anyone had the same problem?

```
\documentclass[
    final,
    reprint,
    notitlepage,
    narroweqnarray,
    inline,
    twoside
    ]{ieee}

\newcommand{\latexiie}{\LaTeX2{\Large$_\varepsilon$}}

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
  \subfloat[one]{\label{fig:one}\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{figures/one.png}}
  \qquad
 \subfloat[two]{\label{fig:two}\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{figures/two.png}}
  \caption{some text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

In the output document:

> Fig 1. Some text
>
> figure

I want to get rid of that last "figure"

UPDATE:

```
\begin{table}[!t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{a caption not displaying OK} 
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
\hline
&Average distance (km) & Total distance (km)\\ \hline
set 1&5.137&102.749\\
set 2&1.602&32.058\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{distances}
\end{table}
```

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The captions are already defined by the `ieee.cls`. Hence the captions can not be defined by the `subfig` package. You should use `caption=false` as the option for `subfig` package.

```
\documentclass[
    final,
    reprint,
    notitlepage,
    narroweqnarray,
    inline,
    twoside
    ]{ieee}
\newcommand{\latexiie}{\LaTeX2{\Large$_\varepsilon$}}
%-----------------------------------------
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig} % <---------------------changed here
\setlength{\captionwidth}{\columnwidth} %<-----------------Add this to correct table captions
%-----------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \subfloat[one]{\label{fig:one}\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{figures/one.png}}
  \hfill
 \subfloat[two]{\label{fig:two}\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{figures/two.png}}
  \caption{some text representing the caption of the current figure properly}
\end{figure}
%--------------------------------------
\begin{table}[!t]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{a caption displaying OK}
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
\hline
&Average distance (km) & Total distance (km)\\ \hline
set 1&5.137&102.749\\
set 2&1.602&32.058\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:distances}
\end{table}
%--------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** The `ieee.cls` provides a length `\captionwidth`. You can define it to be column width like `\setlength{\captionwidth}{\columnwidth}` so that table captions are fixed. I have modified the above code accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! that solved the problem. However, a table  table I am using is not displaying right. I am modifying the example to include my table

Comment: @csr I fixed this problem also. see my edited answer.

Comment: excellent! the caption is displaying well now. Thank you.